# Using Website from Windows form

Tags: c#, .net, web

That is the using website form Windows form, I mean,think a button in a website i want to click on it but ı want to this from my windows form, for example when I click the button on the form, the clean button in translate.yandex will run.

Answer (score 0):

Create an event *Click* for you button, and write inside the method

```
System.Diagnostics.Process.Start("http://www.yandex.com");
```

Comment: thanks but i didnt mean that i mean think a button in a website i want to click on it but ı want to this from my windows form thanks for answer...